# Casting of Integer to String in perl for DB insertion

Tags: database, string, perl, casting, integer

I have a perl script which reads rows from text file and inserts into db.

## Sample text file can look like this

```
country   zipcode
------------------
India      712501
India      00032
```

where first row is column name and the rows denote column value. It is stored as EAV format with both column name and column value as  VARCHAR.

Now for zipcode 00032 the perl script is thinking it as Integer and  the insert query is becoming 
INSERT VALUES('India',00032) //Quote is not coming as perl is treating it as String
SO while inserting it is inserting India 32 (treating it as integer)

So can I make it String by force so the perl module puts VALUES('India','00032') instead ??

Comment: So, why not just add the quotes to your SQL query? Show the relevant part of the code you are using!

Comment: Did you try putting quotes around '00032'?

Comment: I expected the same.  I did a "'"."$value"."'"; but then it is doing '''00032'''. AM i doing something wrong ??

Comment: Why not something like this: `$str = "VALUES ('$country', '$code')";`. But even better if you show your code, you probably want to use `prepare` for your SQL queries.

Answer (score 2):

Putting your data into the query before you 'prepare' can lead to any number of problems.  Use Placeholders.  This way perl knows what datatype is expected in each field and will almost always do the right thing...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is quite a good answer already, but you can still improve it to make it more helpful. Add an example, link to the relevant documentation and explain what the problems are. That way, other people will better understand what you mean, your answer can be used as a reference in the future and you will probably get more upvotes (if you care about a "score", that is).

Answer (score 1):

Perl will only make it a number if you treat it like a number.

```
$x = "00032";
say $x;
$x += 0;
say $x;
```

Output:

```
00032
32
```

You didn't show the code where your postcode string is set, but, if you use `$postcode = "00032";` instead of `$postcode = 00032;`, then the leading zeros will be preserved.  If the value is coming from a file, user input, etc., then something in the code that moves the external data into your program is causing them to be lost, but we can't say what exactly is losing it without seeing the relevant code.

Comment: The leading zeroes are preserved as I am not doing any arithmethic operation but the problem is i have a insert query "INSERT INTO LOCATION(columnName,columnValue) VALUES(?,?) So  when this is getting executed it is getting INSERT INTO LOCATION(columnName,coloumnValue) VALUES('zipCode',0032) Now in oracle db if you insert like this(without quotes in 0032) and coloumnValue is VARCHAR then oracle internally treats it as number and inserts zipCode,32